# Forgot to migrate free tier Postgres and now my app is empty

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

My project is again live no problems whatsoever, but the database is empty.

I am either trying to restore an old backup to the new Postgres instance or upload a backup from my local disk.

I tried to do `pg:restore` but I don’t know where to grab the backup (from the free Heroku tier).

Comment: The data's gone. Hobby DBs got deleted per https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq.

Comment: Not entirely, I did a backup two days ago and I have the data on my disk. So I'm looking for a way to upload this dump to the new database (that is now not free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer I was looking for by going into some of the most hidden help articles in heroku.

https://help.heroku.com/QG1W7LIJ/how-do-i-restore-a-partial-backup-or-single-table-to-heroku-postgres

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U YOUR_USERNAME-d CONNECTION_URL mydb.dump
```

Had to recreate the backup from the local imported database but at the end it worked flawlessly.